# Automatically Terminating Previously Running Python Interprets when Relaunching in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Is there an option for the Eclipse plugin Pydev which would cause Pydev to automatically terminate any already running python instances when a new python instance is launched?

There is an option in Preferences --> Run/Debug --> General Options --> Remove terminated launches when new launches are created

I would need an option of the type: "Terminate and Remove all launches when new launches are created"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of...

you can do the following: do a regular launch and take a look at the buttons in the PyDev console. There are options to terminate all launches, and to relaunch the last launch terminating the current one -- the shortcuts appear if you hover over the buttons:

So (provided you have focus on a PyDev editor):

- terminate all launches: Ctrl+Alt+F9
- terminate current and relaunch it: Ctrl+Shift+F9

Not exactly what you want, but I think it's the closer it gets right now...