# Exit a running program with Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, pydev

I have written a small part of the script below

```
import Image
import threading
im = Image.open("/home/xxx/Desktop/front.jpg")
print im.format, im.size, im.mode
im.show()
```

Is there a way to close or exit a picture (front.jpg) that I have open using commands?

Answer (score 0):

You mean exit a program after launching it from inside Eclipse?

If that's it, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821218/110451 -- which explains how to terminate all running launches or relaunch the current one (you can look under the keybindings and look for 'terminate' there too).

Comment: The problem is that if the background thread is running, it may take some amount of time greater than 0 to respond to the kill. But, otherwise.. yeah. Terminate all.